# LyX does not recognise texlive directory on Mac

Tags: lyx, mac, lyx-layouts

I installed my TeX Live through Macports. There is no problem if I compile my `.tex` with `xelatex` in a terminal. But LyX only "knows" the texlive basic packages with are located at `/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/`.

But the extra features of TeX Live are put separately by Macports into `/opt/local/share/`.

I added the latter into the "PATH" of LyX and reconfigured it again and again but still LyX never sees the extra packages.

I have no idea what's wrong with LyX on Mac!

Comment: Why install TeXLive through MacPorts anyway?  It makes much more sense to install the full MacTeX distribution.  However, since you have also installed the MacTeX basic, you should have a control panel that can switch between the two distributions.  Go to System Preferences (for your whole machine) and click on the TeX Distribution control panel.  The MacPorts one should show up there, I think.  Choose it and try running LyX again.

Comment: LyX is probably not the problem here. Make sure texhash can find the necessary folders. In LyX if your LaTeX distribution is set up properly the only think you need to do is go to "reconfigure" from the LyX menu and then restart LyX.

Comment: It finally worked after I installed MacTeX and reconfigured LyX. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately almost all Mac installation problems can be solved by installing the full MacTeX distribution. As far as I can tell there is never any reason to us a distribution such as MacPorts for TeX on the Mac, and doing so can lead to various other problems (as you have found out.)

For some related discussion see:

- [Adding a CTAN package to a MacPorts-maintained TeX installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50470/2693)
- [What are the practical differences between installing LaTeX from MacTeX or MacPorts/Homebrew?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97183/2693)
- [Package not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17186/2693)
- [How do I install a style file on Mac 10.8? (Other answers don't seem to work.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121257/2693)
- [Why is the MacTeX distribution so large? Is there anything smaller for OS X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/974/2693)